# Remove the part of image, js and css url

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I need to remove the part of image, css and js urls so that I would keep everything that goes after "."
For example,
https://test.com/en/images/footer-inst-icon.svg
I would like to have only "svg" in another column

Here is the link to the file https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1VJPQzkgZCTaKCgRbstVFDCwycZFfCbSL1ENXPYcioNo/edit#gid=0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below formula (see your sheet)-

```
=ArrayFormula(TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(A2:A,".",REPT(" ",100)),100)))
```

You can also use `REGEXEXTRACT()` like

```
=ArrayFormula(REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A,"\w+$"))
```

[image]